# How to create distortion effect using CIFilter as the images under link

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-image, cifilter

I'm looking to add an effect into my app (Live Filtering Recorder App) using core image filter. This effect needs to show distortion lines appearing just like old time recorders. I tried it by loading image frames and applying as overlay to the output of the filters image but that create a lag into the recording. So i'm not looking to generate this effect by CIFILTERS now.

[Tape Recorder like Distortion Lines](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuzobrspmcrnz45/lines.zip?dl=0)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for a custom kernel.

You can generate a random noise field with `CIRandomGenerator` and then use some custom Core Image Kernel Language to composite it over your original image in stripes using `sin` to control the spacing. Passing the sine of the vertical position through a `smoothstep` gives a nice effect.

You kernel should look something like:

```
    let kernel = CIColorKernel(string:
        "kernel vec4 vhsNoise(__sample image, __sample noise, float time, float spacing, float stripeHeight, float backgroundNoise)" +
            "{" +
            "   vec2 uv = destCoord();" +

            "   float stripe = smoothstep(1.0 - stripeHeight, 1.0, sin((time + uv.y) / spacing)); " +

            "   return image + (noise * noise * stripe) + (noise * backgroundNoise);" +
        "}"
        )!
```

I've actually written a `CIFilter` to do this which you can [find here](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia/blob/master/Filterpedia/customFilters/CRTFilter.swift).

Simon

Comment: The above code should use destCoord() instead of samplerCoord(image).  The samplerCoord() function takes a "sampler" not a "__sample".

Comment: Indeed - schoolboy error on my part. That's now changed, although it did work with `samplerCoord`.